# Use of sizeof and _countof in memcpy_s in C [VS2010]

Tags: arrays, visual-studio-2010, int, sizeof, memcpy

I am planning to use the secure version of memcpy to copy an int array to another int array. As per [MSDN library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wes2t00f%28VS.80%29.aspx), for an array, how can the function memcpy_s be used?

```
memcpy_s (array_dest, sizeof(array_dest), array_src, sizeof(array_src))
```

or

```
memcpy_s (array_dest, sizeof(array_dest), array_src, _countof(array_src))
```

Comment: Don't use _countof, that returns the number of elements.  You want the number of bytes, so sizeof.

Comment: Thanks, the last parameter in the syntax of memcpy_s says "count" and is a bit mis-leading.